# Deploy Symfony3 project on VPS

Tags: php, apache, symfony, web-deployment

Help my, I don't know how deploy Symfony3 project on VPS server. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Symfony console is not working. PHP version 5.6.
PHP is working, I verified by phpinfo(), but app.dev returned blank page

Comment: give me some feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your [./web/config.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/web/config.php) ? This file may give you some configuration to apply like php extension php-intl in must case when missing

Have you allow access directory with ACL or chmod command line?

Acl method

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

Comment: chmod -r 777 /web

Comment: what does ./web/config.php ? file